# mutate week 1-12 to quarter 1

Tags: r, database, tidyverse, dplyr

My dataset contains information for each day through 48 weeks.
[screenshot of my dataset][1]

I hope to create a new variable called "quarter", and make every observation whose week variable value = 1-12 be labeled as "a", which means "the first quarter"; also, make every observation whose week variable value = 13-24 be labeled as "b", which means "the second quarter".

I tried `mutate()` and `recode()`, it seems that it goes well to mutate only 1 value:

However, when I tried to label the first 12 weeks as quarter "a"; the second 12 weeks as quarter "b",...It fails like:

> Error: unexpected '=' in:
>   "  ungroup(week) %>%
>     mutate(quarter = recode(week, c("1":"12") ="

I wonder how I can fix it. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `?recode`

> This is a vectorised version of switch(): you can replace numeric values based on their position, and character values by their name. This is an S3 generic: dplyr provides methods for numeric, character, and factors. For logical vectors, use if_else(). For more complicated criteria, use case_when().

So you'd probably need to use `case_when()`

```
total_activity %>% 
ungroup(week) %>%
mutate(quarter = case_when(week %in% c("1":"12") ~ "a",
                           week %in% c("13":"24") ~ "b",
                           week %in% c("25":"36") ~ "c",
                           week %in% c("37":"48") ~ "d"))
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `cut`

```
cut(total_activity$week, c(-Inf, 12, 24, 36, 48), letters[1:4])
```

---

Or another option is using a named vector to replace the values by matching

```
names(setNames(1:48, rep(letters[1:4], each = 12))[total_activity$week])
```

Answer (score 0):

Something to consider is just to use the lubricate package and just use variables for week, and quarter respectively to make sure you always have this info. This is assuming you have a date variable for each observation and you are referring to standard quarters, which it sounds like you are! You'll need to install the package first of course.

```
    library(lubridate)
    total_activity$Datevar <- mdy(Datevar) #this may change based on your date's format Month/Day/Year is very common.
    new.df <- total_activity %>% group_by(Day= day(day), Week= week(Datevar), Quarter= quarter(Datevar)) %>%
    mutate(total_activity= total_activity)
```

That may be a more generalizable way to solve the interval problem rather than just hard coding in a few intervals yourself.